# Time variable - PHP not updating database field

Tags: php

I've got a form that allows the user to input an ID and a duration. If the duration is less than or equal to an hour, then 10 minutes are added to a field called `MaintenanceFlightTime`, If the duration is more than an hour, 15 minutes are added. `MaintenanceFlightTime` and `ID` are in a separate table to where `Duration` is stored, however `ID` is a foreign key in `Duration`'s table.

I've got three files: the form, the insertion script for `ID` and `Duration`, and the updating script for `MaintenanceFlightTime`. The insertion script works fine but the updating script simply isn't working.

Form:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Add Flight</title>
  </head><body>
    <form action="insert.php" method="post">
      <p>
        <label for="ID">ID:</label>
        <input type="text" name="ID" id="ID">
      </p>
      <p>
        <label for="Duration"> Duration:</label>
        <input type="time" name="Duration" id="Duration">
      </p>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Insert `ID` & `Duration`:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "dbname";

$ID = $_POST['ID'];
$Duration = $_POST['Duration'];

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "INSERT INTO InfoTable (ID, Duration) 
VALUES ('$ID', '$Duration')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

  include 'maintenance.php';

$conn->close();
```

Calculate & Update `MaintenanceFlightTime`:

```
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "dbname";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$parsedDuration = explode(':', $Duration);

$hours = intval($parsedDuration[0]);
$mins  = intval($parsedDuration[1]);

if ($hours > 0 && $mins > 0) {
    echo "Added 15 maintenance minutes to $ID!";
    $MaintenanceDuration = strtotime('0:15:00');
} else {
    echo "Added 10 maintenance minutes to $ID!";
    $MaintenanceDuration = strtotime('0:10:00');
}

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Maintenance added successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$MaintenanceDuration = strftime('%H:%M', $MaintenanceDuration);
echo $MaintenanceDuration;

$sql = "UPDATE MaintenanceTable  
SET MaintenanceFlightTime = MaintenanceFlightTime + $MaintenanceDuration 
WHERE ID = $ID";
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Where is the updating script called ? Only the ```insert.php``` script is called in the code you posted. Or is it the ```include 'maintenance.php'``` ?Also, does it echo anything ?

Comment: Yes, it is the `include 'maintenance.php'`. It echoes correctly `"Added 15/10 maintenance minutes to $ID!"` but just isn't updating the field in the database.

Comment: You're not actually running the SQL that you generate in the update script.

Comment: Did you copy the whole script ? Because if you did, nothing is going to happen if you only have the ```$sql``` variable ! You need to ```$conn->query($sql)``` just like you did above.

Comment: You have no DB code in the maintenance script. All you do is define a string that contains some SQL. And note that you are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com).

Comment: I updated the code to include database code. It now echoes `"Maintenance added successfully"` despite not updating the field still.

Comment: You need to set the new value of $sql before you use it again...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
$hours = intval($parsedDuration[0]);
$mins  = intval($parsedDuration[1]);

if ($hours > 0 && $mins > 0) {
    echo "Added 15 maintenance minutes to $ID!";
    $MaintenanceDuration = 15;
} else {
    echo "Added 10 maintenance minutes to $ID!";
    $MaintenanceDuration = 10;
}

echo $MaintenanceDuration;

$sql = "UPDATE MaintenanceTable SET MaintenanceFlightTime
=(MaintenanceFlightTime + INTERVAL $MaintenanceDuration MINUTE)
WHERE ID = $ID";
```

Comment: Sorry, this does not update the field either. No errors though.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to change the variable in the query. Please try now.

Comment: No result, sorry! Thank you anyway

Comment: Fixed. I tested this query and now it is ok